# Autoconf How To Include Data

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I am creating a spellcheck program that uses a dictionary called `english.dict`. I need this installed in `$datadir` (I am using autoconf and automake). I have tried doing it this way:

```
CFLAGS = -m32 -Wall 
LDFLAGS = 

bin_PROGRAMS = spellcheck
pkgdata_DATA = english.dict
spellcheck_SOURCES = spellcheck.cpp meta.cpp 
spellcheck_LDADD = ../libspellcheck/libspellcheck.a
```

But when running make:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck'
Making all in libspellcheck
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck/libspellcheck'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck/libspellcheck'
Making all in spellcheck
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck/spellcheck'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `english.dict', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck/spellcheck'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/iandun/libspellcheck-devel/libspellcheck'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried numerous ways, as well as read the official documentation and other stack overflow questions and still cannot figure this out. I'm probably stupid, but I don't know what to do...

Comment: Does libspellcheck/spellcheck/english.dict actually exist?  From the error message I would think not.

Comment: Wow. It wasn't there. After I placed it in the directory everything worked.

Comment: Do not set `CFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`.  `CFLAGS` is a user variable and should only be set by the user (the person/process running `configure`).  If you must, set `AM_CFLAGS`